# Cache-control with Oracle ORDS

Tags: cache-control, oracle-ords

My DB gets new data only between 1pm-2pm. Users jump back and forth, often looking at the same thing multiple times, I want to use caching to cut network load.  My response type is:

```
source_type_collection_item
   Executes a SQL Query returning one row of data into a ORDS Standard JSON representation. 
   Available when the HTTP method is GET. 
   Result Format: JSON
```

single row SYS_REFCURSOR response with multiple nested CURSORS.

```
FUNCTION my_func RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
   my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN my_cursor FOR
   SELECT value, CURSOR(SELECT value_2, CURSOR(SELECT ... FROM table)
...
```

I want to set differing cache-control based on server time:

- Request at 9:30am - cache 3.5 hrs
- Request at 1:30pm - cache 0 mins
- Request at 3:30pm - cache 21.5 hrs

The problem is that I can't figure out how to set caching **at all** for an ORDS endpoint returning HTTP GET.  I have one working fine for an unrelated PL/SQL service

```
   source_type_plsql :-
      Executes an anonymous PL/SQL block and transforms any OUT or IN/OUT parameters into a JSON representation. 
      Available only when the HTTP method is DELETE, PUT, or POST. 
      Result Format: JSON
```

using a defined parameter:

```
    ords.define_parameter(
       p_module_name         => l_module_name,
       p_pattern             => l_pattern,
       p_method              => l_method,
       p_name                => 'Cache-Control',
       p_bind_variable_name  => 'cache_control',
       p_source_type         => 'HEADER',
       p_param_type          => 'STRING',
       p_access_method       => 'OUT',
       p_comments            => '');
```

But this won't work for the GET case because:

1. HTTP GET is unsupported by PL/SQL
2. SYS_REFCURSOR as ORDS PL/SQL out parameter unsupported

---

The only option I could figure out was a static cache setting in Tomcat rather than ORDS.

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>ExpiresByType application/json</param-name>
      <param-value>access plus 30 minutes</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/ords/*</url-pattern>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

But that's undesirable for a number of reasons:

1. It applies to ALL services under ORDS but caching is a bad idea for most other endpoints.  I was unable to filter more precisely than this - from Tomcat's point of view it seems that ORDS is a monolith and gets one cache control setting.
2. It is a fixed value.

Comment: did you get this sorted? client caches are based on e-tags which could help.

Comment: @KrisRice No, I did not get it sorted.  Had to leave it and move on to other things a few months ago.